# Generic Tester Class

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics

Greetings Java Wizzards,

I'm having difficulties with passing a generic list from my tester class to my main class.  The purpose of this assignment is to shift the last element in the list to the first location in the list, and shift the remaining members of the list right one unit.  Currently, when I run the tester, I receive the following error.

> Unable to locate executable for jre1.8.0_20.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Task1<E> {
/*
 * implement a method for KWArrayList(as a generic) that removes an elements fron the end of
 * the list and inserts it at the lists beginning
 * 
 * 2. following example of section 2.3, do not invoke other KWArrayList methods.
 * 
 * 3. Write a test program proving that it works for ArrayLists having sizes 1,2,5
 * 
 * 4. upload class and test class zipped together.
 */
    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

    private E[] theData;
    private int capacity = 0;

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Task1() {
            capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
            theData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        }


    public void frontOfTheLine(Object item ){

        int end = theData.length - 1;
        theData[0]=theData[end];

        for (int i = end; i>0 ;i--)
        {
            theData[i]= theData[i-1];
        }


        for(int counter = 0;counter< theData.length;counter++)
            System.out.printf( "%5d%8d\n",counter,theData[counter]);

    }   
}
    public class Task1Tester {


    private static Object item1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // we need a test array of length 1, 2, and 5

        Task1<Object> theData = new Task1<Object>();
         item1 = "a";
        theData.frontOfTheLine(item1);

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this from an IDE like eclipse?

Comment: Something like this : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/833475/ ?

Comment: Yes, I am running it through eclipse.